# How come is form_tag by default is POST in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I type rake routes it shows the following:

```
 Helper HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url          

publicos_tematica_path   GET     /publicos/tematica(.:format)    publicos#tematica
```

Why do I have to explicitly write the GET method in the form_tag, otherwise it come up 
No route matches [POST] "/publicos/tematica" if routes says GET ?

```
<%= form_tag("publicos/tematica", :method => :get) do %>
```

I don't GET it.

It should be enough writing:

```
<%= form_tag("publicos/tematica") do %>
```